# Using CooCox as an alternative to Keil MDK-ARM - any limitations?

Tags: microcontroller, c, development-tools, stm32f4, keil

A very popular and advertised tool for programming ARM microcontrollers is Keil MDK-ARM. The evaluation version can be [downloaded here](https://www.keil.com/demo/eval/armv4.htm). However there is a code-size limitation of 32 kB for using the evaluation version of Keil. After some searching I found out that the [CooCox IDE](http://www.coocox.org/index.html) is a free alternative to Keil and similar software.

So my question, given that CooCox is absolutely free is... Is CooCox an alternative with no such limitations of code-size, etc.?

Comment: The 32KB limitation applies to the compiler,linker,debugger and simulator. You can use the MDK-Lite Keil uVision IDE without the code size limitations for compiling, linking and programming GCC projects.

Comment: @Tut - Can you please point me to some resource that explains how to use MDK-Lite Keil uVision IDE with GCC projects, without code size limtitations ? And also the download link fo that particular version. In fact you could turn it into an answer.

Comment: I'll give it to you in a nutshell. If you need more, we can go to chat. I used Sourcery CodeBench Lite for ARM EABI available [here](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/). For the project in uVision4, go to Project-Manage-Components,Environment,Books... and select the Folders/Extensions tab. Check "Use GCC". The tool prefix I have is "arm-none-eabi-" and the GNU-Tool Folder is the base folder of the installed toolchain, in my case: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI\".

Comment: @JamesC the MDK-Lite 32KB limit still applies for debugging, even if you use GCC, so it's pretty much useless for debugging anything non-trivial because the 32KB is calculated from the sum of code & data, not just code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CooCox (by default, at least) uses the GCC compiler (tautology alert!), which is completely free.  I've been using CooCox for postgrad work and, although there are a few issues with the IDE (because it's Eclipse-based - make of that what you will...) I have found it to be very usable when compared to MDK-ARM (which I use at my day job).

CooCox (and GCC) have no code size limitations that I am aware of, and CooCox integrates very nicely with the STLINKv2 (including the built-in STLINKv2 on the ST32F Disco boards) for cheap STM32F debugging.